# Simple jQuery textarea does not expand on load

Tags: jquery, textarea, expand

The following is a simple textarea script written in jQuery that expands each textarea to fit the contents as the user is typing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
       var addin = 0;
       var txtheight = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(txtheight > 0){ addin = 4; }
       $(this).height(($(this).height() + txtheight + addin));
    });
    $('textarea').keyup();
});
```

Problem is, if the initial content of the textarea is greater than one line, the textarea does not expand to fit the content on load as the scroll position cannot be computed.

Any ideas how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you give this plugin a try?

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Comment: this is a perfect example, i was searching for something like this! thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea').each(function() {
       var addin = 0;
       var txtheight = $(this).prop("scrollHeight") -  $(this).height();
       if(txtheight > 0){ addin = 4; }
       $(this).height(($(this).height() + txtheight + addin));
    });
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
       var addin = 0;
       var txtheight = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(txtheight > 0){ addin = 4; }
       $(this).height(($(this).height() + txtheight + addin));
    });
    $('textarea').keyup();
});​
```

However scroll height is not supported by anything less than IE8 it looks.

Comment: That does not work and crashes the function on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @RobinKnight works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSZq5/) on Chrome and Firefox for me. Your solution is more succinct though, I merely just copied, pasted, edited what he had working.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).height($(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
    $('textarea').keyup(function() {
       var addin = 0;
       var txtheight = $(this).scrollTop();
       if(txtheight > 0){ addin = 4; }
       $(this).height(($(this).height() + txtheight + addin));
    });
```

Correct use of `'scrollHeight'` as outlined from Danny.